# Problems getting Maven docbkx plugin to work

Tags: maven, xslt, customization, maven-plugin, docbook

I have been experimenting with generating DocBook output using Maven running within Eclipse. I found the Maven plugin called docbkx, and it almost gets me there.

In the DocBook world, the way that you change some of the default behavior of the XSL transformations is by defining your own XSL file as a "customization layer." This file imports the standard XSL file and then any templates, etc. that you want to change are put in this file. Thereby, they are parsed after the standard templates, and your altered version is what is used.

To make this happen using the docbkx plugin, you have to tell it that you are using a custom XSL file in the configuration, with lines like

```
<foCustomization>src/docbkx/xsl/custom_print.xsl</foCustomization>
```

Then, in the custom XSL file, instead of needing to specify the location of the standard XSL file in the import statement at the top, you put in a symbolic path that the plug-in resolves:

```
<xsl:import href="urn:docbkx:stylesheet"/>
```

This all works very well. But I have been banging my head against the wall trying to understand how the plugin can be told to look for *other* things you might want to import. Two examples:

- my customization layers import not just the regular stylesheet, but
  also a custom titlepages XSL file I generated by the usual process.
- I have a template to write a chunk of additional code into the HTML
  output's head element. Specifically, it's the code to hook up to
  Google Analytics. The code is in an external file.

In both cases the files being imported are sitting in the same directory as the customization layer, but best as I can tell the plugin can't find them. I don't know how to get the plugin to include these as it does its work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Alan

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like:

```
src
|
+--docbkx
   |
   +--xsl
      |
      +--custom_print.xsl
      +--custom_titlepages.xsl
```

and a pom like:

```
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.agilejava.docbkx</groupId>
    <artifactId>docbkx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    ...
    <foCustomization>src/docbkx/xsl/custom_print.xsl</foCustomization>
    ...
```

include in your `custom_print.xsl` the `custom_titlepages.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:import href="urn:docbkx:stylesheet"/>
    <xsl:include href="custom_titlepages.xsl"/>
```

You might find enlightening these documents:

- [Advanced Customization](http://docbkx-tools.sourceforge.net/advanced.html)
- [Customizing both HTML and FO](http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/CustomMethods.html#CustomizingBoth)